# Hover button to make image change to grayscale 100% css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my image into grayscale 100% while hovering the button. The problem is it does not become greyscale image while hovering the Button. I have tried to use `:active,:hover` but it doesn't solve my issue.

```css
#image1:hover {
   filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.button1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  left:0;
  top: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .35s ease;
}
.button1 a {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 12px 48px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ff991e;
  border: 1px solid #ff991e;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.image-1:hover .button1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

div.button1:hover > #image1 {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 image-1">
  <img src="http://servesphere.com.ph/moto/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Left-image.png" class="" id="image1" style="width: auto; height: 320px;">
  <div class="centered">
    <p class="title1">BRAND NEW</p>
    <div class="button1"><a href="#"> ENTER </a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make the button a sibling of your image? Then you can use: `.button1:hover + #image1{ ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.button-div a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 100px;
  padding: 12px 48px;
  color: #ff991e;
  border: 1px solid #ff991e;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bolder;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity .35s ease;
}

.button-div img {
  width: auto; 
  height: 320px;
  position: relative;
}

.button-div:hover a.button {
  opacity: 1;
}

.button-div a:hover + #image1 {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 image-1">
    <div class="button-div">
      <a class="button" href="#"> ENTER </a>
      <img src="http://servesphere.com.ph/moto/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Left-image.png" class="" id="image1" style="">
    </div>
  
  <div class="centered">
   <p class="title1">BRAND NEW</p> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

Check this out.

Comment: hello thanks for answering once i hover my image the button will show up and once button shown up and hover it the image must be grayscle too

Comment: But it does, maybe it's your browser problem?

Comment: i dont know why, can you check my codes ? are you available for teamviewer ?

Comment: First of all. tell me which browser are u using?

And just for sure:
user hover BUTTON, then BUTTONS shows up and IMAGE go greyscale. user leave BUTTON and BUTTON hides, IMAGE goes normal color, right?

Comment: im using google chrome, hover image > show button > hover button > image must be grayscale, all grayscale are working but the only thing is when i hover button the image go to normal(without grayscale)

Comment: Now I get it :)

Comment: Please look at code snippet once more.

Comment: Thanks! @Krzysztof Mazur you got it!